# Merge Spark dataframe rows based on key column in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have a streaming Dataframe with 2 columns. A key column represented as String and an objects column which is an array containing one object element. I want to be able to merge records or rows in the Dataframe with the same key such that the merged records form an array of objects.

```
Dataframe

----------------------------------------------------------------
|key    | objects                                              |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|abc    | [{"name": "file", "type": "sample", "code": "123"}]  |
|abc    | [{"name": "image", "type": "sample", "code": "456"}] |
|xyz    | [{"name": "doc", "type": "sample", "code": "707"}]   |
----------------------------------------------------------------


Merged Dataframe

-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|key   |  objects                                                        |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
|abc   |    [{"name": "file", "type": "sample", "code": "123"}, {"name": 
            "image", "type": "sample", "code": "456"}]                   |
|xyz   |   [{"name": "doc", "type": "sample", "code": "707"}]            |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

One option to do this to convert this into a PairedRDD and apply the reduceByKey function, but I'd prefer to do this with Dataframes if possible since it'd more optimal. Is there any way to do this with Dataframes without compromising on performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming column `objects` is an array of a single JSON string, here's how you can merge `objects` by `key`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

case class Obj(name: String, `type`: String, code: String)

val df = Seq(
    ("abc", Obj("file", "sample", "123")),
    ("abc", Obj("image", "sample", "456")),
    ("xyz", Obj("doc", "sample", "707"))
  ).
  toDF("key", "object").
  select($"key", array(to_json($"object")).as("objects"))

df.show(false)
// +---+-----------------------------------------------+
// |key|objects                                        |
// +---+-----------------------------------------------+
// |abc|[{"name":"file","type":"sample","code":"123"}] |
// |abc|[{"name":"image","type":"sample","code":"456"}]|
// |xyz|[{"name":"doc","type":"sample","code":"707"}]  |
// +---+-----------------------------------------------+

df.groupBy($"key").agg(collect_list($"objects"(0)).as("objects")).
  show(false)
// +---+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
// |key|objects                                                                                      |
// +---+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
// |xyz|[{"name":"doc","type":"sample","code":"707"}]                                                |
// |abc|[{"name":"file","type":"sample","code":"123"}, {"name":"image","type":"sample","code":"456"}]|
// +---+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks Leo! This worked for me with a minor edit. (collect_list($"objects"(0)).as("objects")) fails with "org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Field name should be String Literal, but it's 0;". I got it working without specifying the index since anyways the objects column will have only one element and the index wasn't required.

Comment: @bytecode, not sure why `$"objects"(0)` doesn't work in your environment.  I would suggest that you try `$"objects".getItem(0)`.  `collect_list` on the entire Array column will result in a nested Array of WrappedArray, rather than an Array of JSON strings as shown in your expected result dataset.

Comment: Explicitly calling getItem on $"objects" works. Not sure why the shorthand didn't work.

Comment: BTW, is there any way to do this without the aggregate function?

Comment: Since your requirement is to aggregate elements of the `objects` array per `key`, I don't see any way not to apply certain aggregate function.